# laptop screen blinks continuously, Ubuntu and Win7 Display settings show's there is a connected external monitor

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors

The screen blinks continuously (Usually, On startup. It blinks when it show's there is another monitor connected or if that same monitor disconnects), it shows that an external display is connected, it also gets disconnected after a few times (from that unknown external display), but I didn't plug any other monitors. Does anybody know why this is happening and how to stop it?

[image]

Same with Windows 7.

Comment: It doesn't blink all the time.
Usually, it blinks on startup.
It blinks when it show's there is another monitor or if that monitor disconnect

Comment: Thanks. For the future, it's better to update your question to answer in comments. This way the relevant details are readily available for the community members without digging through comments. I corrected now "continuously" to "randomly" as per your statement. My comments have served their purpose, so I will remove them to leave space for more relevant commentaries :-)